# Is there a way to do Single Sign On for the Microsoft Bot framework webchat via the DirectLine API and an Azure Web App using an Oauth2.0 abstraction

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, botframework, single-sign-on

The idea here is to do a SPA application with an implementation of a Microsoft Bot which will be embedded into an Azure Web App. The application will use an Oauth2 openId connect login that will take in other logins such as Google, GitHub, Facebook and Microsoft credentials.

I know that I can authenticate the conversation to include a userId in the tokenization of the bot. That [documentation is here.](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/)

The question I have from that is what about if I have a login [pathway to a dialog such as is explained here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cjavascript#additional-information) 
The issue I see is that having a site login won't activate the needed token for logging into the bot so it can call other api services. Or can I extract the token from the web browser effectively and use that for the token I need to obtain user info such as email or login and hash to access a service?

I want the same route protection and activation for inside of the bot if the user signs into the site outside of the bot without having them sign into the bot again.

What can I do to have the site token act upon the botframework itself?

But, if the user where using the bot in another channel per se Facebook they would still have to log into the bot to go down certain dialog pathways.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [SSO sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps/e.sso-on-behalf-of-authentication) in the WebChat repo?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I think is best is to take the notes from the [original blog post I posted in the original question.](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/01/using-webchat-with-azure-bot-services-authentication/)

So the plan is, with this code.

```js
// Generates a Direct Line token 
server.post('/directline/token', (req, res) => { 
  const options = { 
    method: 'POST', 
    uri: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', 
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.directLineSecret}` 
    }, 
    json: { 
      User: { 
        Id: userId 
      } 
    } 
  }; 
  request.post(options, (error, response, body) => { 
    if (!error && response.statusCode < 300) { 
      res.send({ 
        token: body.token 
      }); 
    } else { 
      res.status(500).send('Call to retrieve token from DirectLine failed'); 
    } 
  });
```

You would grab the id and user info from the localstorage and use that to pass the id into the conversation token creation as the controller above is illustrating.  Once this has been passed into the bot the bot know is "aware" of the userId and you can now use this information as authentication for the bot then on out instead of querying it yourself.  Also, this id would be used for the users other api calls downstream too.